# Problema para visualizar relatório utilizando Crystal Reports no Visual Studio 2017

Tags: view, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

Estou com problema para visualizar informações de relatório utilizando Crystal Reports no Visual Studio 2017.

Quando abro um arquivo RPT ele é visualizado da seguinte forma:

[image: arquivo rpt]

Sendo que ele deveria abrir o relatório com os componentes criado. O problema ocorreu quando tive que desinstalar e instalar novamente um versão do Crystal. A versão que estou usando é a 13.0.18 do Crystal.

Eu tenho instalado o runtime engine for .NET Framework, caso seja uma informação útil para ajuda.

Comment: Também tive o mesmo problema precisei desinstalar tudo tanto o Visual 2017 quanto o Crystal e refiz a instalação no meu caso resolveu espero que ajude.

Comment: Provavelmente você instalou o Crystal Reports e posteriormente instalou a versão dos desenvolvedores, desinstala os a versão dos desenvolvedores e o Crystal normal e posteriormente faça o download somente da versão dos desenvolvedores, segue o link
https://www.sap.com/brazil/products/crystal-visual-studio.html